# Jersey Spring-Security HTML AJAX not working as expected

Tags: rest, spring-security, jersey, java-ee-6, web-applications

Currently it secures the jsp pages and can display them BUT the REST endpoints CAN NOT be found (404 for all rest AJAX Calls).  I have done other things to change it were it finds the rest endpoints, but then the HTML cant be found and the security checks arent being performed.

What am I missing?

security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
    <http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
         <intercept-url pattern="/login-page.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
         <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page='/login-page.html' default-target-url="/static-page.jsp" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED 
                    from USERS where USERNAME=?" 
                authorities-by-username-query="
                    select U.USERNAME, UR.AUTHORITY from USERS U, ROLES UR 
                    where U.USERNAME=UR.USERNAME and U.USERNAME=?"      
            />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:server-context.xml, classpath:spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>service.admin</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test-app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Under webapp folder I have the js & css & images folders plus the *.html and *.jsp files  under WEB-INF is where the web.xml folder is.  Is there someplace else I should put the html files and how would I map it in the web.xml.

Comment: You may actually want to break this up into 2 separate questions. You'll likely get better answers as the people attending to you won't get distracted in conflicting details.

Comment: Let's assume this one is about your second question:  'can it work for HTML pages as well?' What do you mean can it work for HTML pages?

Comment: Done removed the second questions, but to answer your question, can spring-security secure static html files and force login if not logged in

Comment: Yes! I've done this in my app. I'll have to boot up my other computer and look at my code before posting an example.

Comment: I appreciate it, this thing has been driving me crazy, first time using spring-security and i keep getting it almost there, but not quite all the way.  And with so many different ways to do things its a maze to follow

Comment: Can you also help with the main question?  Basically if i get it to work with securing .jsp the rest methods all end up in 404, if i get it where it can find the rest methods (changing  <url-pattern>/test-app/*</url-pattern>
to  <url-pattern/*</url-pattern>
)  then it cant find the html or jsp PLUS the rest endpoints are not secured.

Comment: So you mentioned you are using Jersey. Not sure if the mvc:resources mapping will work for you. Let me know! Also, regarding the REST calls, I think we'd need to see more code for that one, and it may actually be better as a separate question as well so we don't clutter this one up too much :)

Comment: I don't see a http security entry for the pattern /test-app. That's your REST pattern, right? I think you'd need to add an entry for it too.

Comment: so the <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
doesnt cover that?

Comment: Oh, good point. You should be ok then as far as that goes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10923/discussion-between-jmort253-and-user1357437)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to secure your HTML files, you'll first need to place them in a secure location. The WEB-INF folder is the only folder deployed in your application that is not accessible by HTTP; thus, a folder there is a good place to keep your HTML files. I recommend /WEB-INF/html.

Next, you'll need to tell Spring to map all requests for *.html to the /WEB-INF/html folder. This needs to be placed inside a  xml element in your Spring servlet.xml file.

html-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/WEB-INF/html/" />
```

See [How To Secure MVC Resources](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110490-How-to-secure-lt-mvc-resources-gt) for more information.

You'll need to add some http entries in your security.xml file for each HTML file:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/users-only.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

This uses the Spring filter to check the resource and redirect it based on the user's role.

Lastly, you'll need an entry in web.xml for a servlet that handles requests to *.html:

web.xml:

```
<!--  Security -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>html</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/html-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!--  Secure static HTML files. See applicationContext-Security.xml intercept-url for individual HTML file control over security.-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>html</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do I have to use spring-webmvc for this?

Comment: I think it's the Spring Web package. You'd have to try it out. I'd think as long as you can make sure all requests to *.html are handled by a servlet that goes through the Security filter, it may work. It took some time to get this to work for me, and I'm using Spring 3.0.5 with Spring security 3.0.7 on Google App Engine.

Comment: You may be able to map *.html in a separate Jersey servlet, but without seeing the Jersey mappings I can't be much help as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: It does the redirect for the HTML and the REST ENDPOINTS but it gets a 404 for the login page, i tried to add this <form-login login-page='/html/login-page.html' default-target-url="/html/static-page.html" />  had it as this <form-login login-page=/login-page.html' default-target-url="/static-page.html" /> and both result in 404

Comment: I had many issues that jmort253 so graciously walked me through.  the biggest issue was not fully understanding what everything was doing.  Basically the rest was able to be found and was secured but I was accessing it from the wrong url.  the rest jmort253 explains perfect.